# How can I see the code behind all the widgets on a NetLogo Interface?

Tags: netlogo

I am looking at a NetLogo model with lots of widgets. Which of them have code behind them?  What global variables are hidden behind them? Which procedures do they call? How do I find out?

Solution (1): Open each widget one at a time, then look at what's back there. Make notes because I have to close this one to open the next one.

Solution (2): View the nlogo file in a text editor, scrolling down past the Code section, and dig out the widget code from all those numbers.

Neither of those solutions are very pleasant or fast.

What I would like is a quick way to see what lurks behind the widgets on the Interface.  Is there a tool that will do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  (update Jan 2017)

At [modelingcommons.org][1], download **nivi**.

nivi stands for "NetLogo Interface Variables Information". It is a NetLogo 6.0 file that parses the information about the widgets into a report that you can read on the screen or copy/paste.

It requires version 6.0 of NetLogo, but will use files created by earlier versions of NetLogo as data.

[1] http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/4962